# Polynomial regression not producing lines of best fit

Tags: r, correlation, polynomial-math

I am trying to create a polynomial equation by plotting known depths on two cores along my y and x-axis. Theoretically, this means that I can enter a depth from one core into the equation to get the depth on the other. Basically I am trying to correlate the two cores as best as possible.

However, I am finding that my output values deviate significantly (I enter a value knowing the output but it is vastly different). I am also concerned about the high r2 values.

The main questions I have are as below: 
1: Is this issue due to my lack of understanding around statistics or failure within my code
2: Is what I want to achieve even possible?
3: Will I just have to accept the seemingly large margins for error.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have battled with this on my own to no end for too long now.

[image: Graph Output]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

setwd("/Users/jakobparrish/Dropbox/Jakob/2019/Lake Nganoke-Thesis Prep/Core Work/Hyperspectral-Chlorophyl 'A'/Graphs R/Chlorophyll A")
SPEC <-read_csv("Correlations.csv")
Correlations <-read_csv("Correlations.csv")

lm_eqn <- function(df, degree, raw=TRUE){
  m <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree, raw=raw), df)  # get the fit
  cf <- round(coef(m), 5)  # round the coefficients
  r2 <- round(summary(m)$r.squared, 5)  # round the r.squared
  powers <- paste0("^", seq(length(cf)-1))  # create the powers for the equation
  powers[1] <- ""  # remove the first one as it's redundant (x^1 = x)
  # first check the sign of the coefficient and assign +/- and paste it with
  # the appropriate *italic(x)^power. collapse the list into a string
  pcf <- paste0(ifelse(sign(cf[-1])==1, " + ", " - "), abs(cf[-1]),
                paste0("*italic(x)", powers), collapse = "")
  # paste the rest of the equation together
  eq <- paste0("italic(y) == ", cf[1], pcf, "*','", "~italic(r)^2==", r2)
  eq
}

###############################
#Plots LC1U vs LC3U
df1 <- data.frame("x"=Correlations$LC3U, "y"=Correlations$LC1U)
df1 <- na.omit(df1)

p1v3 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()+
  labs(x ='LC3U [cm]', y ='LC1U [cm]', title = 'Core Correlations of Lake Nganoke LC1U & LC3U') +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), size = 1) +
  annotate("text", x = 10, y = 10, label = lm_eqn(df1, 2, raw = TRUE),
           hjust = 0, family = "Times", parse = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)) + #add limits in
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)) +
  expand_limits(y=c(10,90),x=c(10,90)) +
  theme_classic()

p1v3

###############################
#Plots LC2U vs LC3U
df2 <- data.frame("x"=Correlations$LC3U, "y"=Correlations$LC2U)
df2 <- na.omit(df2)

p2v3 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()+
  labs(x ='LC3U [cm]', y ='LC2U [cm]', title = 'Core Correlations of Lake Nganoke LC2U & LC3U') +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 4, raw = TRUE), size = 1) +
  annotate("text", x = 10, y = 10, label = lm_eqn(df2, 4, raw = TRUE),
           hjust = 0, family = "Times", parse = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)) + #add limits in
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)) +
  expand_limits(y=c(10,90),x=c(10,90)) +
  theme_classic() 


p2v3

#################################
#Plots all two together

P_Correlations <-plot_grid(p1v3, p2v3, labels = "AUTO")

P_Correlations
```

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Hi Jake, please try to limit your post to one question at the time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ) and provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) please. Then it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: @majid Sorry! I will definitely try and clear up my questioning. Relatively new so still trying to work out the best way to frame everything :-)

Comment: Unless you have reason to believe your model is a 4th order, you should avoid higher order polynomial fits, they are notoriously unstable beyond the fitted data points. With only 7 or 8 data points to fit 5 terms you run a high risk of over-fitting.

Comment: Looked into your suggestion @DaveT, and it was correct. I was under the assumption that the greater the polynomial the greater the degree of accuracy. Obviously I was wrong. Cheers for the help